# Issue with Local server and Live server wordpress Migration

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I have developed a wordpress website on my local server which works perfectly. The shopping experience of adding items to the basket and checkout works as expected but when I transferred it to the live server, this stops working correctly (the Mini Cart doesn’t update, and items get deleted automatically).

Despite previous suspicions, there is no custom code involved – the only variable is the live server.

I wonder if you please advise on what might possibly be going on, and if you’ve seen something similar before – perhaps cache/refresh/something else??

The website is approaching the launch date, and this is the final mystery!

Site: http://www.test2.hydro-x.co.uk/

Comment: it's working correctly..

Comment: Hi Bilal, 
Thanks for your comment bilal, Sorry it is not working. if you click on the basket icon @ zero Item, the minicat js does not pop out. add two I tem to the basket, basket and navigate to another page (the basket wont work either). Meanwhile everything works instantly on my local server.

Comment: look this https://prnt.sc/gpfrbr and http://prntscr.com/gpfrm2

Comment: clear the browser cache and cookies

Comment: Logo still loading from localhost. First do check and confirm everything is loading from live server.

Comment: The brower cahce and cookies was cleared, I have tried it on several system and still doesnt work.
Look at this https://prntscr.com/gpfy8d and https://prntscr.com/gpg1kf and https://prntscr.com/gpg1hq

Comment: @AnupGC thanks. Can you please guide me on now to check if everything is loading from live server. I have already made the redirection for all the links.

Comment: change the browser or system.. then how it is working on my browser..?

Comment: Hi @BilalAhmed, I have tried different browser, different comupter system but still doesnt work. I could see that the logo isnt comming up on other system. see this on internet expoler http://prntscr.com/gpg6f4
Can I ask, if the minicat poped out when you click on the basket with zero item?